# Delete statement with variable after DELETE

Tags: t-sql, sql-delete

Can someone please explain what this does?  I'm referring to the `@comps` straight after delete - the docs seem to suggest it places the deleted rows into `@comps`, is this true?  `@comps` is a table variable.

```
delete @comps
from @comps as a
where a.compcode = '43423'
```

Comment: I don't think this is valid T-SQL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx

Comment: @Oded maybe, but it works... I've tested in MsSql2005

Answer (score 5):

You are reading the docs wrong. To put the deleted rows into a table variable you would use the `OUTPUT` clause (see example `g` [in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) for that)

The relevant part of the syntax here is

```
DELETE 
    [ FROM ] 
    { <object> | rowset_function_limited 
    [ FROM <table_source> [ ,...n ] ]
```

Your query is missing the first optional `FROM` so the first reference to `@comps` is the target table for deletion. The second (aliased reference) is documented in BOL as follows

> **FROM `<table_source>`**
>
> Specifies an additional FROM clause.
>   This Transact-SQL extension to DELETE
>   allows specifying data from
>    and deleting the
>   corresponding rows from the table in
>   the first FROM clause.
>
> This extension, specifying a join, can
>   be used instead of a subquery in the
>   WHERE clause to identify rows to be
>   removed.

In terms of explaining what is happening in your query however the documentation seems to be lacking. A self join gets treated differently from a join onto a different table.

```
declare @comps table (compcode char(5))
declare @T table (compcode char(5))

INSERT INTO @comps VALUES ('12345')
INSERT INTO @comps VALUES ('43423')

/*Copy the table*/
insert into @T
select * from @comps

delete @comps
from @T as a
where a.compcode = '43423'

select * from @comps /*The table is empty. For every row in @comps the 
                       join on a.compcode = '43423' returns a match so
                       all rows get deleted*/



/*Add back the deleted rows*/
INSERT INTO @comps VALUES ('12345')
INSERT INTO @comps VALUES ('43423')

/*Try the self join*/
delete @comps
from @comps as a
where a.compcode = '43423'

SELECT * FROM @comps /*Returns 12345*/
```

The plans are below

[image: External Join]

[image: Self Join]

Comment: @BertuPG - As far as I understand the OP is asking about what the syntax means. My answer at the moment is I'm not sure but I find the behaviour above confusing.

Comment: you have edited your code, but it's still different from original posted by asker, in any case this code produce a non empty result:

`
declare @comps as table (compcode varchar(10))

insert into @comps VALUES('1111')
insert into @comps VALUES('2222')
insert into @comps VALUES('3333')
insert into @comps VALUES('4444')

delete @comps
from @comps a
where a.compcode = '4444'

select * from @comps
`
(Sorry, but i wasn't able to insert new line in comment)

Comment: @BertuPG - I know. It is deliberate. The OP's question is asking about the two different usages of `@comps` as far as I can see.

Comment: sorry, my english is not so good, after reading more times the question, I understood, and now I think the answer is "No, deleted rows will not be copied". Anyway, I voted up your answer ;)

Comment: I'm not sure it is correct to describe the OP code as a self-join. `a` and `@comp` is the same. The query plan for a self-join has two table scans and a Hash Match (at least for me).

Comment: @Mikael - I agree that it isn't treated as a self join. It seems to be treated as a reference to the table in the first `FROM` I just find it very confusing and inconsistent. `delete a from @comps as a where a.compcode = '43423'` works so it seems optional whether you use the aliased or non aliased table name here. I can't think of anywhere else in SQL Server where you can give a table an alias then reference it unaliased without it being treated as a self join.

Comment: @Martin - See my post below with the `@comps is ambiguous` error, explains a lot. BTW `update` statement works the same as `Delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are right. In this code, "@comps" can only be a table variable.

You can also write

```
delete from @comps where compcode = '43423'
```

It's totally equivalent

Answer (score 0):

@comps and a is the same table referenced with different aliases.

This is also valid and do the exact same thing.

```
delete a
from @comps as a
where a.compcode = '43423'
```

The fact that it is the same is best show with this sample

```
delete @comps
from @comps as a
  inner join @comps as b
    on a.compcode = b.compcode
where a.compcode = '43423'
```

This will give you error

```
Msg 8154, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The table '@comps' is ambiguous.
```

SQL Server does not know which @comps to delete from, a or b.

**Edit 1**
I see now that this is probably more of a comment to Martin's post. Not an answer to the OP about what is in the docs.